# Config files and references: which one is loaded?

Tags: asp.net

I have two projects inside a solution.

Project one is a vb.net console app, that does some operations on a SQL server database.

Project two is a asp.net dashboard, that shows to the users the results of the operations done by project one, reading them from a table in the same db.

Each project takes its properties for connecting the db from its config file. (exe.config for the console app, and web.config for the website).
Then I had to make project to able to run a subset of the operations of project one, so I made a function in project one that runs that subset, and added project one to the references of project two.
And everything works.

Then I had to leave localhost and move my projects to the client server.
So I have the publish folder of the Asp.net site which contains in the bin folder the exe file of project one.

I edited the configs to set the right credential for logging in to the server SQL, and when I run project one everything works. When I run project 2 everything works. When I try to run the subset of project one within project 2, the connection string created shows the original settings and not the edited one.

So my question is: where do they come from?

Both the cfg files are correct, and each application is able to connect, except for the subset stuff.
If I call a function of a referenced file, which config file does it read?

Comment: If the web application is referencing an assembly, regardless of what that assembly is, and executing code within that assembly then I would expect the web application's config file to apply in that scenario.  Though without seeing exactly what you're doing we can't know for certain what you're doing.  However, in general I would recommend not referencing *applications* from each other, but instead creating a Class Library project which each application references.  A class library has no config and clearly uses the config of the application calling it.

Comment: So you think that a class library would be better suited for my needs? I'll try to move my project in that direction. But just a question. In the class connecting to the db in the class library, how do I reference the properties of the caller settings file?
I mean, right now I write

Dim builder As New SqlConnectionStringBuilder()
builder.DataSource = My.Settings.SERVER

In the dll version, with no settings, how do I call it?

Comment: I'm not sure what `My.Settings` is in your code.  For reading application config files I've always just used `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager`.

Comment: And that reads the config file of the caller?

Comment: It reads the config of the running application.  When reading anything from the application config file (`App.config` or `Web.config`) I would expect any approach to read from the configuration of the currently running application.  Why your example doesn't could be an indication of anything, really.  The question contains a lot of description of what you're doing, but contains no code demonstrating any of it.  To better diagnose any problems in code, this is a good starting reference: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example